# Как получить два наибольших значения из столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

Из подобного DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Car": ['Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_3', 'Model_1', 'Model_3', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_3'], 
  "City": ['Moscow', 'Moscow', 'Perm', 'Perm', 'Omsk', 'Omsk', 'Orel', 'Tula', 'Tula', 'Kazan', 'Voronez', 'Voronez', 'Voronez', 'Kazan', 'Kazan', 'Omsk']})
```

делаю `groupby`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('Car')['City'].value_counts())
```

и получаю такой DataFrame:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне из него получить топ-2 значения столбца `City` и расположить их по-столбцам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо, за помощь!

Comment: Можете привести пример данных в виде текста или CSV, так чтобы мы смогли использовать эти данные для решения?

Comment: Да. Создавал такой dataframe: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Car": ['Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_3', 'Model_1', 'Model_3', 'Model_2', 'Model_2',
                           'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_3'], 
                    "City": ['Moscow', 'Moscow', 'Perm', 'Perm', 'Omsk', 'Omsk', 'Orel', 'Tula', 'Tula', 'Kazan', 
                             'Voronez', 'Voronez', 'Voronez', 'Kazan', 'Kazan', 'Omsk']})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Car": ['Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_3', 'Model_1', 'Model_3', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_1', 'Model_2', 'Model_2', 'Model_3'], 
  "City": ['Moscow', 'Moscow', 'Perm', 'Perm', 'Omsk', 'Omsk', 'Orel', 'Tula', 'Tula', 'Kazan', 'Voronez', 'Voronez', 'Voronez', 'Kazan', 'Kazan', 'Omsk']})

r = df1.groupby("Car")["City"].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))
res = (r
       .reset_index()
       .assign(top=["Top_1", "Top_2"] * df1["Car"].nunique())
       .pivot(index="Car", columns="top", values="City")
       .rename_axis(None)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

---

результат:

```
In [73]: res
Out[73]:
         Top_1  Top_2
Model_1      3      2
Model_2      3      2
Model_3      2      1
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!!! Буду разбираться как это работает, но очень полезное преобразование для моих данных! Как тебе лайк поставить? Или проголосовать? =))

Comment: Отметил! Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: дома у меня сработало на версии pandas 1.0.1, а на работе стоит 0.24.2 и там выдает ошибку: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign' Как под эту версию подправить?

Comment: Очень странно! После применения “reset_index()”, Series должен был превратиться в DataFrame. Вы код случайно не меняли?

Comment: Ну и версия 0.24.2 сильно устаревшая конечно

Comment: я просто сделал pd.DataFrame из Series и этот этап заработал. Теперь ругается на pivot: пишет KeyError: 'Car' в строке .pivot(index="Car", columns="top", values="City")

Comment: А если запустить весь код из моего ответа, не меняя его, на Pandas 0.24.2 - тоже ругается?

Comment: заработало! Как-то непонятно, почему в таком виде заработало =)) Теперь всплыла ещё одна тонкость: есть такие Car, по которым встречается только один City, поэтому топ-2 у них нет, только топ-1. Пока сделал только топ-1, не соображу как нули вставить в таком случае в столбец топ-2 =) Спасибо, что комментишь